# nodemailer cannot send mails to specified receipting through gmail

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hi here is my code i am trying to send mail through nodemailer module
i am accessing it through POSTMAN tool.

```
      userRouter.post('/forgetPassword', function(req,res){
    userModel.findOne({'email': req.body.email}, function(err,foundUser ){
        if(!foundUser){
            var myResponse = responseGenerator.generate(true,"please check 
                             your email id", 404 , null);
            res.send(myResponse);
        }
        else if (err) {
            var myResponse = responseGenerator.generate(true,"entered wrong 
             email id", 404 , null);
            res.send(myResponse);
        }
        else{
           var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
              service : "gmail",
              auth: {
                user: 'kota.raavi@gmail.com',
                pass: 'my original password'
              }
            });
            var mailOptions = {
              from: 'Ravi Kota <kota.raavi@gmail.com>',
              to: 'foundUser.email',
              subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
              text: 'here is the required token by which you can reset your 
               password and the same will be updated!'
             `enter code here`};

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                var myResponse = responseGenerator.generate(true,"entered 
               coming here wrong email id", 404 , null);
                //res.send(myResponse);
              } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
                //var myResponse = responseGenerator.generate(false,"check 
                 your modified inbox", 200 , info);
                //res.send(myResponse);
              }
            });

        }
    });
});// end forgetPassrword
```

in the above code response generator is a middleware that i created seperately for showing the results

while i am executing i encountered with the following error

```
{ Error: No recipients defined
    at SMTPConnection._formatError 
(C:\weaversdirect\mvcApp2\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-
connection\index.js:577:19)
    at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope 
(C:\weaversdirect\mvcApp2\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-
connection\index.js:786:34)
    at SMTPConnection.send 
(C:\weaversdirect\mvcApp2\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-
 connection\index.js:408:14)
    at sendMessage 
 (C:\weaversdirect\mvcApp2\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-
 transport\index.js:219:28)
    at connection.login.err 
 (C:\weaversdirect\mvcApp2\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-
 transport\index.js:276:25)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete 
 (C:\weaversdirect\mvcApp2\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-
connection\index.js:1320:9)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str 
 (C:\weaversdirect\mvcApp2\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-
 connection\index.js:349:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse 
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:547:20) code: 'EENVELOPE', command: 'API' }
    POST /users/forgetPassword - - ms - -
```

please correct me where i am doing mistake
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mailOptions = {
          from: 'Ravi Kota <kota.raavi@gmail.com>',
          to: foundUser.email,
          subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
          text: 'here is the required token by which you can reset your 
           password and the same will be updated!'
         `enter code here`};
```

Answer (score 0):

change `to: 'foundUser.email'`

to `to: foundUser.email`